# Iterate through table rows and set an image in specific tds

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a few rows. I want to insert a image on specific rows depending on some results.

This code I'm currently setting the background color for these rows (depending on dates), but cannot figure out how to insert an image instead.

```
$('#table tbody tr').each(function () {
    var document = $(this).find('.date1').html();
    var rule = $(this).find('.date2').html();

    if (document < rule) {
        $(this).addClass('backgroundColor');
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Got it to work with this (thanks to @Milind Anantwar & @kapantzak):

`$('td.notify', this).append('<img src="../Images/notification.png" />');`

Comment: can you show us the html code? Also where do you want to insert the image?

Comment: what problem you are facing ? is this code not working ?

Comment: HTML and CSS code plz...

Comment: Add a background-image to the class-rule instead of, or as well as, a background-color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (document < rule) {
    $(this).addClass('backgroundColor');
    $(this).find('td.your_class').append('<img src="path/to/img" alt="image" />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the background image for row via css, then you can set `background-image` to image url using:

```
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

for appending image inside td element:

```
$('td',this).append('<img src="imgurl" />');
```

Comment: Yes, this is setting all the td's within the row. But just wanted to set the first (or a class named td), sorry if I was unclear. Thanks tho, got it to work with yours combined with @kapantzak.